# Capybara Connection Refused

Tags: ruby, selenium, capybara

I am using Capybara with Selenium in Ruby (not within a testing framework.)

If I open a ruby console and run the method, it works, but if i then run the same method again I get this error.

```
    Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - connect(2)
from /home/ross/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:762:in `initialize'
from /home/ross/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:762:in `open'
from /home/ross/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:762:in `block in connect'
from /home/ross/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:54:in `timeout'
from /home/ross/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:99:in `timeout'
from /home/ross/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:762:in `connect'
from /home/ross/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:755:in `do_start'
from /home/ross/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:744:in `start'
from /home/ross/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1284:in `request'
from /home/ross/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.26.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:83:in `response_for'
from /home/ross/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.26.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:39:in `request'
from /home/ross/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.26.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:40:in `call'
from /home/ross/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.26.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:598:in `raw_execute'
from /home/ross/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.26.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:576:in `execute'
from /home/ross/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.26.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:99:in `get'
from /home/ross/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.26.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/navigation.rb:14:in `to'
from /home/ross/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/capybara-2.0.1/lib/capybara/selenium/driver.rb:34:in `visit'
from /home/ross/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/capybara-2.0.1/lib/capybara/session.rb:180:in `visit'
from /home/ross/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/capybara-2.0.1/lib/capybara/dsl.rb:51:in `block (2 levels) in <module:DSL>'
```

The code is like the following:

```
class ExampleClass
  include Capybara::DSL

  def do_capybara

    Capybara.app_host =  "http://example.com"
    Capybara.run_server = false
    Capybara.current_driver = :selenium

    visit '/'

    page.driver.browser.close

    Capybara.reset_sessions!
  end
```

Comment: If you type `reload!` after getting this error does it work again? If so maybe try removing `page.driver.browser.close` and `Capybara.reset_sessions!`

Comment: What if you try without the line `Capybara.app_host = "http://example.com"`? AFAIK, Selenium uses host `127.0.0.1`.

Answer (score 2):

Could you tried after set some default time.

```
Capybara.default_wait_time = 10
```

Just give this comment after set the current driver. It may help you to overcome from the issue.